# Service "findItemsByKeywords" of APi Ebay not return results exacts (PHP)

Tags: php, api, ebay-api

I have a problem with the Ebay API, in particular with the service or operation "findItemsByKeywords", since according to the URL to which you make the query to return to the results (itemSearchURL) it is very different from the one that returns me when printing on screen. Then I show you my code.

```
print_r($ebay= ebayapi("Xiaomi Redmi Note 7"));
function ebayapi($keyword) {
// API request variables
$endpoint = 'http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1';  // URL to call
$version = '1.13.0';  // API version supported by your application
$appid = '';  // Replace with your own AppID
$globalid = 'EBAY-ES';  // Global ID of the eBay site you want to search (e.g., EBAY-DE)

$safequery = urlencode($keyword);  // Make the query URL-friendly
$i = '0';  // Initialize the item filter index to 0

// Construct the findItemsByKeywords HTTP GET call 
$apicall = "$endpoint?";
$apicall .= "OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords";
$apicall .= "&SERVICE-VERSION=$version";
$apicall .= "&SECURITY-APPNAME=$appid";
$apicall .= "&GLOBAL-ID=$globalid";
$apicall .= "&keywords=$safequery";
$apicall .= "&categoryId=9355";
$apicall .= "&bestOfferEnabled=true";
$apicall .= "&SortOrderType=StartTimeNewest";
$apicall .= "&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=3";

$resp = simplexml_load_file($apicall);

$fiction=array();

if ($resp->ack == "Success") {
  $results = '';

  foreach($resp->searchResult->item as $item) {
    $price  = $item->sellingStatus->currentPrice;
    $title = $item->title;
    $pic   = $item->galleryURL;
    $url= $item->viewItemURL;
$title2=remove_accents($title);
$price2=(float)$price;
$uid= uniqid(about);
$uid2= uniqid(price);
 $fiction[$uid]=  array('price' => $price2,
        'priceOld' => '0',
        'percentageSaved' => 0,
        'currency' => '&euro;',
        'currencyCode' => 'EUR',
"manufacturer" => "",
"category" => "",
"categoryPath" => "",
"merchant" => "",
"logo" => "",
"domain" => "ebay.com",
"rating" => 4.5,
"reviewsCount"=>"",
"availability"=>"",
"orig_url"=>"$url",
"ean"=>"",
"upc"=>"",
"sku"=>"",
"isbn"=>"",
"woo_sync"=>"mobile",
"woo_attr"=>"",
"unique_id"=>$uid2,
"title"=>"$title2",
"description"=>"dezcripcion",
"img"=>"$pic",
"url"=>"$url",
"last_update"=>"1576704317",
"extra" => array("deeplink" => "")
);

  }
return $fiction;
}

else {
 return "AppID for the Production environment.";
}
}
```

supposedly, when making a var_dump to the api response, you should get the data from the following url: https://www.ebay.es/sch/i.html?_nkw=Xiaomi+Redmi+Note+7&_ddo=1&_ipg= 3 & _pgn = 1

But I did not get anything from them, or at least not in the desired order, instead I got "Xiaomi Redmi Note 8 Pro 6GB 128GB 6.53", "Xiaomi Redmi Note 8 Pro 128GB 6GB 6.53" Smartphone NFC 4500mAh Global ROM ", only one had a match" SMARTPHONE XIAOMI REDMI NOTE 7 128GB FREE 5379335 ". How could I give more precision and that the given keyword be governed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `findItemsByKeywords`, use `findItemsAdvanced`.  I don't think they've updated `findItemsByKeywords` in years, and people have reported problems using it.  That said, I've also heard that the results you retrieve from the API will differ from the results you get on eBay itself.  On eBay, searches will be "fuzzy", meaning you're much more likely to get results you don't want.  The API is typically very strict about the results you will receive; if you search for item title only, and you search for "Xiaomi Redmi Note 7", you will *only* get results that include all four keywords.

Comment: I have tried the service you mentioned, there is a slight improvement, but I still find different searches on the screen than in the url to which it mentions, example: "Xiaomi Redmi Note 8 Pro 128GB 6GB 6.53" Smartphone NFC 4500mAh Global ROM "

Comment: And it's not in: https://www.ebay.es/sch/9355/i.html?_nkw=Xiaomi+Redmi+Note+7&fscurrency=EUR&_ddo=1&_ipg=3&_mPrRngCbx=1&_pgn=1&_udlo=10

Comment: As I said, the search on eBay.com is fuzzy.  So going to your search link, I see "Xiaomi Redmi Note 8".  The API might ignore single digits, so it's pulling ""Xiaomi Redmi Note" in the title.  Try and use a keyword that's not a single letter or digit to narrow it down.